# Where to put templates in Django 1.4?

Tags: python, django, frameworks

I got a bit confused, because when I use the generic ListView class, Django is looking for "appname/objectname_list.html" inside the "appname/templates" folder. This results in:

```
appname/templates/appname/objectname_list.html
```

If I supply "template_name", it does not require the subfolder inside the templates folder anymore.

Why doesn't it find the objectname_list.html inside the "templates" folder like before in 1.3 ? Did I configure something wrong or did they change the place where I'm supposed to put my templates as well ? In 1.3 I used to place template html files inside "appname/templates" directly instead of using a subfolder.

For me it does not make sense to use another subfolder with the name of the app, where the templates folder is already in. Or am I missing something useful ?

I could not find anything about it in the release notes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think this is 1.4 specific.  If you will want your template in a subfolder, specify `template_name = 'subfolde/template.html'`

Regarding template dirs, from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#loader-types):

> ... For each app in
>   INSTALLED_APPS, the loader looks for a templates subdirectory. If the
>   directory exists, Django looks for templates in there.

So the actual dir is:

```
projectname/appname/templates/appname/objectname_list.html
            ^^^               ^^^
```

This helps you keep everything inside the app folder and does not require you to configure anything,

This also means that if you have apps `foo`, `bar` and `baz`, you can still have one `templates` dir under one of the apps:

```
myproj/foo/templates/foo/...
myproj/foo/templates/bar/...
myproj/foo/templates/baz/...
```

Comment: So what's the use of the additional sub folder ? Is it so I can cut&paste the templates easier to another place ? It just looks weird to have the appname multiple times.

Comment: It allows you to override/modify templates of another app, i.e. `myproj/foo/templates/admin/base_site.html`

Comment: Isn't that very untidy ? I get that the subfolder is useful in projname/templates/appname/template.py.
But overriding templates of one app inside anther entangles them very much.

Well anyway, thank you very much !